# Golang SSH load LD_PRELOAD and LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variables

Tags: go, ssh, socks

I'm trying to connect to a remote server using [Golang SSH package](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/ssh), but there's a SOCKS between my workstation and this remote server.

I'm able to connect to the server by simply setting a LD_PRELOAD and LD_LIBRARY_PATH and then running:

```
$ export LD_PRELOAD="/path/to/lib"
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/path/to/lib"
$ ssh user@hostname
```

But when I set these variables within the Go code, it doesn't work:

```
os.Setenv("LD_PRELOAD", "/path/to/file")
os.Setenv("LD_LIBRARY_PATH", "/path/to/file")
```

If I set these variables within the Go code and try the following, it works:

```
ssh := exec.Command("ssh", "hostname")
output, _ := ssh.Output()
fmt.Println(string(output))
```

The ssh PermitUserEnvironment is set as yes

Is there any way to "force" the Golang SSH to use these environment variables?

Comment: LD_PRELOAD and LD_LIBRARY_PATH have nothing to do with ssh itself, that is injecting some shared libraries into your openssh process. If you don't use the openssh binary, you can't preload a different shared library into it.

Answer (score 1):

(Edit: This answer does not necessarily apply to Go 1.8 and above. See comments for discussion)

`LD_PRELOAD` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` are environment variables processed by the [dynamic linker](https://www.cs.virginia.edu/~dww4s/articles/ld_linux.html) when a program is starting up. If you set those environment variables inside the program, they don't have an effect on the program itself since the linker didn't see them.

On the other hand, the environment variables will affect external applications that you run (the `ssh` command for example) from within the program, since the linker is given control to resolve the shared libraries that the application uses.

<s>If you instead set those environment variables before running the Go program, I think you'll have the desired effect.</s> (This is only applicable if the compiled program is linked to the shared standard C library. See @JimB's comments below for more details.)

Comment: No, this won't have the desired effect, because Go doesn't use the C library socket calls to be overridden. Chances are that the Go program doesn't use any C shared libraries at runtime (though the std lib uses cgo for the resolver and user db when enabled), and may be completely statically linked

Comment: @JimB thanks for pointing that out! I have updated my answer based on your comment, after a quick verification that it was indeed the case.

Comment: Are you sure about that? The `Dial()` function in the `ssh` package uses `DialTimeout()` from the `net` package. I wrote a simple program that used `DialTimeout()` and I was able to use `LD_PRELOAD` to tunnel through a `SOCKS` proxy. (This was on Linux with `CGO_ENABLED` set to true / undefined. `go build` generated a dynamically linked executable which I tested..)

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot that it only needs to intercept Dial. However I thought current versions of Go had started defaulting to the native Dialer unless required by the local config files. What version of Go are you using? (even so, you could still `export GODEBUG=netdns=cgo` to force the cgo resolver)

Comment: I used go1.8.3 linux/amd64. With my setup, the `cgo` resolver is used by default and I have to explicitly force it to use the Go resolver. Looks like there are a bunch of [conditions](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#hdr-Name_Resolution) when that might be the case.

Comment: OK, that's what I thought. So if you want to rely on LD_PRELOAD, you will need to force the host resolver in _all_ cases, which you can do with `GODEBUG=netdns=cgo` or building with the `netcgo` tag.